# Docker compose ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : COPY failed: forbidden path

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm following the official docker tutorial to set up rails in docker the link of the same is given below

https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/

My Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY ../compose /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The error which I'm getting when run this command

```
docker-compose run --no-deps web rails new . --force --database=postgresql
```

Error:

```
Step 7/12 : COPY ../compose /myapp
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : COPY failed: forbidden path outside the build context: ../compose ()
```

My dir structure is

```
docker-rails tree.
├── Dockerfile
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── docker-compose.yml
└── entrypoint.sh

0 directories, 5 files
```

I'm relatively new to docker setups. I saw similar kind of errors in SO but their set up files are different so couldn't understood how to fix it.

Comment: "*`...forbidden path outside the build context...`*" - The build context is the pwd form which the `dockerfile` is called. We cannot copy data from outside this directory into the container. In short: we cannot use `../` in a `dockerfile`.

Comment: I give upon this and made my backend with Golang. Everything works smoothly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to copy a file that is outside of the build context. the build context according to the documentation of docker-compose:

> Either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a url to a
> git repository.
>
> When the value supplied is a relative path, it is interpreted as
> relative to the location of the Compose file. This directory is also
> the build context that is sent to the Docker daemon.

try changing `COPY ../compose /myapp` to `COPY . .`
and run the build command in a terminal within the directory